# Javascript Sticky Navigation Flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a sticky navigation bar and it's flickering every time it adds the .fixed css.
I've found solutions that other people have used and worked including adding `overflow:auto` and `transform:translateZ(0)`. None of it seemed to work for me.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on("scroll", function(){
    stickyNav();
  });
});

function stickyNav() {
   var navHeight = menu_offset = $('.main-menu').offset().top;
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
             $('nav').addClass('fixed');
         }
         else {
             $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
         }
}
```

```
<nav class="main-menu"> content </nav>

.fixed {
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
overflow:hidden;}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Edit 1:

I made a JSFiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/j44xdv3m/4/)
It's currently not working anymore. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Fiddle and browser+os or it didn't happen ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must cache all used elements before using! Or jquery always finds elements via selectors as new variable.

```
// variables
var mainDocument = $(document);
var stickyNav    = $('nav');
var etc.....

// function definitions
............

// using all
............
```